# How to make so that you can only enter a date?

Tags: c#

So I need to do so in the "Year", you can enter the date only.
To pop up a warning something.
Here's the code, if the user enters an empty value, you need to add?

```
if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox4.Text == "" || textBox5.Text == "" || textBox6.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Не заполнены все поля!");
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Simply parse the content of the date text box and if the parsing fails, then you know that you are not dealing with a valid year value. As an extra, you could also include range checks. As a side note, please use a better naming convention.

Comment: Regex would be good if you have a definite date format ;)

Comment: Why not just use a date control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put together textBox dateTimePicker,  further:
string date=dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString ("dd.mm.yy")

Answer (score 2):

And why in the "Year" the whole date? Plug the NumericUpDown to the limitations of values and the whole business.)))